# Dimension Reduction of Feature in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

Is there any way to reduce the dimension of the following features from 2D coordinate (x,y) to one dimension?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact, there are infinitely many ways to *reduce the dimension* of the features. It's by no means clear, however, how they perform in practice.

A feature reduction usually is done via a principal component analysis (PCA) which involves a singular value decomposition. It finds the directions with highest variance -- that is, those direction in which "something is going on".

In your case, a PCA might find the black line as one of the two principal components:

[image]

The projection of your data onto this one-dimensional subspace than yields the reduced form of your data.

Already with the eye one can see that on this line the three feature sets can be separated -- I coloured the three ranges accordingly. For your example, it is even possible to completely separate the data sets. A new data point then would be classified according to the range in which its projection onto the black line lies (or, more generally, the projection onto the principal component subspace) lies.

Formally, one could obtain a division with further methods that use the PCA-reduced data as input, such as for example clustering methods or a K-nearest neighbour model.

So, yes, in case of your example it could  be possible to make such a strong reduction from 2D to 1D, and, at the same time, even obtain a reasonable model.

Comment: Axis in PCD changes according to the distribution of data. Is there anything that is consistent in different data sets, like the (x,y) coordinate axes?

Comment: @boogiedoll: certainly not. How should that work? You *need* the data, otherwise you have no information at all. However, you could do a SVD based on only a small number of samples, and use that for the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to learn more about feature dimension reduction, other than PCD, do you have any resources to recommend?

Comment: Principal Component Analysis is named as `PCA`. It calculates eigenvectors of the covariance matrix and works on that. On the other hand there is another dimensionality reduction method called as Linear discriminant analysis (LDA). LDA models the difference between classes but PCA does not takes into account it.

Comment: @kamaci:  thanks for correction, I have no idea why I wrote PCD instead of PCA ... :-)

Comment: @davidhigh :) On the other hand are you sure that it is PCA and not LDA?

Comment: @kamaci: quite sure. However, I should note tha PCA from the first only produces a certain subspace (here the one-dimensional black line). What you further do with the reduced representation of the data (--which is represented through the projection onto this subspace) is beyond PCA. So my colouring is not PCA, but rather a nearest neighbours or clustering analysis in the one-dimensional subspace. I'll remark that in the answer.